# Way to automatically convert class method to function taking explicit class argument in Scala?

Tags: function, scala

The following is a manual process

```
case class A(x: Int) { def f(y: Int) = x * y }
val af: (A => Int => Int) = _.f

val a = A(4)
val r = af(a)(2)
```

Is there a conventient way to get a function like `af`? Something like `A magic f`, possibly without using reflection. Ability to import all public methods of a class via `import A#magic._` is a bonus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This way is 10 symbols shorter:

```
val af = (_: A).f _
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of A and import the methods:

```
val a = A(4)
import a._
```

There is no other way of doing this, because `x` needs to hold a value. You could however create a singleton object instead af a class and change your method signatures accordingly:

```
object A {
  def f(x:Int)(y:Int) = x*y
}

import A._
```

As far as i know it is not possible to turn all methods of a class into curried `(constructor)(method signature)` functions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why u want that, but u indeed can achieve the following:

```
scala> case class A(x:Int){ def f(y:Int)=x*y}
defined class A

scala> val af = A(2).f _
af: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> af(3)
res0: Int = 6
```